# __toString function from a ManyToMany join Table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have hit a very weird speed bump and would like extra mind to figure out this logic

I have 3 Entities, Country which stores country details, Language which has language info and finally CountryLanguage which houses country names in different languages.

Now my problem is, I want to display countries names on a dropdown in a particular language say english only using the __toString function.

Please see code below in my Country entity file from which i'm getting this error: **Country::__toString() must return a string value**

```
public function __toString()
{
    $names = $this->getLanguages();
    foreach($names as $name)
    {
        if($name->getLanguage()->getId() == 1 /*id for english */)
        {

    return $name->getCountryName();
        }            
    } 
}
```

I'd be really grateful for your time in helping me solve this

Comment: Hint: You could use ICU with [SonataIntlBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl/master/doc/index.html) here.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback, the issue I am having is not necessarily locale related but the problem is **return $name->getCountryName(); ** is not passing the value back to ChoiceList. How to solve this is what I need help with

Comment: I guess there is no language with ID equal to `1`, so your loop/method ends without returning anything. Add `return "ABCDEF";` at the end of the method to verify that.

Comment: Same error, when I echo `return "ABCDEF";` i get the country name. I suspect it's because it's the loop right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to show you more effective way:

```
$names = $this->getLanguages();

if($names && count($names) > 0)
{
    foreach($names as $name)
    {
        if($name->getLanguage()->getId() == 1)
        {
            return $name->getCountryName();
        }            
    }
}else
{
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this effective solution, the issue ultimately boils down to the country without name in the join table which I hadn't expected. Thanks for taking your time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got this to work like this but i'm not sure it's the cleanest answer and will be open to being corrected.

```
public function __toString()
{
    $names = $this->getLanguages();
    $country = '';
    foreach($names as $name)
    {
        if($name->getLanguage()->getId() == 1)
        {
            $country = $name->getCountryName();
        }            
    } 
    return $country;
}
```

Comment: You want to return here :

        if($name->getLanguage()->getId() == 1)
        {
            return $name->getCountryName();
        }  

or break because otherwise, the loops will go on for no reason

Comment: Isn't this what I have up there? I think I have noticed a potential reason for this, there's a country without an entry in the join table so we have the ID returning blank name

Comment: Yes, but if you find proper name in the "foreach" loop, the looop still goes to the end which is unnecessary because you already found your value already. I added an answer just to show you formatted code